# Error in Android Studio: INSTALL_FAILED_OLDER_SDK

Tags: android, android-studio

I just now installed Android Studio and am porting my project over from Eclipse. When I try to run the app only my phone, which is 4.4.2 (API 19), I get the error `Failure [INSTALL_FAILED_OLDER_SDK]`. My build.gradle looks like this:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 'android-L'
    buildToolsVersion "20.0.0"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.appuccino.collegefeed"
        minSdkVersion 14
        targetSdkVersion 19
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            runProguard false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
}
```

And my AndroidManifest looks uses the following:

```
    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="14"
        android:targetSdkVersion="19" />
```

When I try to run on my device, on the Choose Device dialog under Compatible it says No, minSdk(API 20, L preview) != deviceSdk(API 19).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Drop your `compileSdkVersion` to `19`. `android-L` locks you into only shipping to "L" Developer Preview devices/emulator images.